# For each parameters, script checks if there exists a user of such username. If exists script prints all processes run by this user

Tags: linux, bash

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
        echo "Script Should Have Atleast 1 Parameter"
        exit
fi

USER=$1
echo $USER

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        echo " Yes the User Exists"
else
        echo "No , The User Doesnt Exists"
fi
```

My problem here is whatever the input i give, it shows yes the user exists.
And can anyone suggest me a command to print out all the process runs by this user
Should i use awk , or grep

Answer (score 5):

Well, first of all, you are not checking if user exists, but ultimately if command `echo $USER` didn't fail. You will need to implement proper user check.

Good way how to check if arbitrary user exists would be something like this, using command `id`.

```sh
if id "${1}" &> /dev/null; then
    echo 'user found'
else
    echo 'user not found'
fi
```

Next you want to list all processes belonging to this user. You will need `ps`. There are many ways how `ps` can format output. Be sure to check manual page of `ps`. Here is example which lists command and pid of all processes belonging to user in `"$1"`.

```sh
ps -eo pid,comm --user $(id -u "${1}")
```

At last, running check using `id` and only then using `ps` for process list is inefficient at least. In your use-case, you can simply run `ps` and check if it was successful. If not, you can show warning that user was not found.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if ! ps -u "$1" 2> /dev/null; then
  echo 'user not exists!'
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thats working perfectly thank you so much ,

Comment: one more question please , how to list : The result should be group by username and formatted as follow .
username – Name and Surname
PID command